# Why my if statement is not working properly?

Tags: java, if-statement

This is an ATM program which I have been tasked to do for class.  I am having a problem with this function.  The account cannot go below 25, if so the transaction must be declined.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Can I get some advice?

```
public void withDrawal(double amount) 
{ 
    if(getbalance() > =  25 && getbalance() > amount)
    {       
        super.setwithdraws(amount);         
                    withdrawlsCheck();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," WITHDRAW SUCCESSFULL");
    }

    if(getbalance() <= 25 && getbalance() < amount)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Transaction Declined !!!! Your account must have at least $25 ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((getBalance() - amount) < 25) {
  don't do the transaction
else {
  do the transaction
}
```

Also please use camelCase properly.

And one more thought on style.  25 should really be declared as a constant, not left hanging around as a "magic number".

Comment: Thank You for your help this worked Flawlessly.  I will pay more attention to my camel casing.

Answer (score 0):

1. `> =` doesn't mean much, you probably want `>=`.  I'm guessing that that's what you've actually got, this is just a typo in your post.
2. You don't want `>= 25` on one condition and `<= 25` on the other.  Try `< 25` so that 25 isn't covered by both conditions.
3. Your logic should be checking the balance *after* the withdrawal, not before.  `getBalance() > (amount + 25)` is closer to what you want.
4. Your logic covers only two of four scenarios.  You've got "enough balance and at least 25", "not enough balance and at most 25".. what about "enough balance and at most 25" and "not enough balance and at least 25"?  Note that this point is unimportant once points 2 and 3 are implemented; I'm just commenting on how you came up with the logic initially.